How to redirect to homepage in Django if already logged in and then try to access /accounts/login/?
So I have "django.contrib.auth.urls" to implement login in my app called accounts. I also have set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
in settings.
When I log in it redirects me to the home page as I have set it up in a template below. The problem is when I am logged in and then try to go to /accounts/login/, it still redirects me to login page.
I couldn't understand how to make it automatically redirect to homepage if user is authenticated and they try to access either 'accounts/login/' or 'accounts/signup/.
I thought this behavior was included in "django.contrib.auth.urls". What do I get wrong?
Here's my project.urls setup:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]

Here's my accounts.urls:
from django.urls import path
from accounts.views import SignUpView, log_out


urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('logout/', log_out, name='logout'),
]

These are my views:
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from accounts.forms import CustomUserCreationForm


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

And this is the template code for home:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Hi {{ user.email }}!
    <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
{% endif %}
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}

I am using Django version 5 and Python 3.12 if this helps too.
Can someone spot a mistake I am making in the code or in my assumptions?
